# babel the code generator has deoptimized the styling of as it exceeds the max of 500kb

Tags: javascript, webpack

Что не так ? как это фиксится?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том что через babel проходят библиотеки из node_modules.

Решение через webpack, добавление exclude:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

Или можете добавить в конфиг babel(.babelrc или babel.config.js) свойство ignore:

```
"ignore": [
    "node_modules"
]
```

Также можете добавить externals для webpack чтобы исключить node_modules из bundle, для этого можно использовать [webpack-node-externals](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-node-externals).

Надеюсь, я помог!